# How to get the "rank" of a Array entry by it's value?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose I have the following structure

```
var Arr = [
  {value: 2},
  {value: 4},
  {value: 1}
]
```

Ok, now i want to "rank" this values by giving them a score of `0 -> n` (the array size is variable) where the biggest value receive the lowest score (0) and the lowest value receives the biggest score (n).

- This logic just need to work with positive integers and zero.

My idea is the create a function that returns the score by the array index

```
getScore(Arr[0]); // 1
getScore(Arr[1]); // 0
getScore(Arr[2]); // 2
```

But i'm really stuck and have no idea on how to do this.

Comment: Sort it, reverse it, and then they are ranked 1-n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run a sort function - then just take the index of each position as it's rank:

```
function getScore(array, val) {
    return array.sort(function(a, b) {
        return b.value - a.value;
    }).map(function(item) { 
        return item.value;
    }).indexOf(val);
}

getScore(Arr, Arr[0].value) //1
```

Comment: Hummm, interesting! Why not to use Array.indexOf instead of for loop, for the sake of neatness?

Comment: @FilipeMerker -- You can do that, I just used the regular `for` for legacy support. Suppose it doesn't matter since we're using `sort` :)

Comment: Edited to use some chained events and `indexOf`

Answer (score 1):

The 'rank' function you describe is equivalent to asking "how many entries in this array are greater than a given value?"

Here's an alternate implementation that takes the approach of simply counting:

```js
function getScore(array, val) {
    var score=0;
    for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++)
      if (array[i].value > val) 
        score++;
    return score;
}

var Arr = [
  {value: 2},
  {value: 4},
  {value: 1}
]
console.log('getScore(Arr, Arr[0].value) →', getScore(Arr, Arr[0].value));
console.log('getScore(Arr, Arr[1].value) →', getScore(Arr, Arr[1].value));
console.log('getScore(Arr, Arr[2].value) →', getScore(Arr, Arr[2].value));
```

This will be bit faster for large arrays because it doesn't have to sort the array, and it will be more compatible with older browsers that don't support the `map` function. The only difference between this implementation and [tymeJV's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38063890/1715579) is how it will handle values that are not present in the original array.

Comment: +1 for performance concern. Although I'm not processing big arrays, maybe some future users may need this. Thank you